# C# - Passing focus to a tabcontrol/page and not being able to mousewheel scroll

Tags: c#, forms, scroll, mousewheel, tabpage

I have a combobox with four items that correspond to tabs in a tabcontrol. When the user selects an item from the combobox (by left clicking and left clicking again to select an item) the corresponding tabpage in the tabcontrol is selected. The tabpage is set to autoscroll but when the tabpage is selected in this way mousewheel scrolling does not work. (If I click a control inside that tabpage manually I can then mousewheel scroll..)

If the user mousewheels to select an item from the same combobox (and successfully passes control to the corresponding tabpage) mousewheel scrolling works fine on that tabpage and I cant figure out why.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (comboBox1.SelectedIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage3;
            tabPage3.Focus();
            break;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you're describing. When the user selects an item from a combobox, that combobox should have the focus. That means all mouse scroll events will scroll the combobox, changing the selected item. You shouldn't expect it to scroll the `TabPage`. And then what does the code you posted have to do with the question? Could you edit your question to provide further clarification?

Comment: well once they make a selection in the combobox that code passes focus to the correct tabpage with the tabpage3.Focus(); line. There's really no other relevant code to the question.

Comment: Ah, so the problem lies with that code snippet? That's not at all clear to me from the question. Are the misspellings in your actual code? (Always copy and paste from your IDE to StackOverflow questions, or we'll be debugging the wrong things!)

Comment: No, i just edited down the code to be more generic. The problem lies in the fact that once focus is passed to the tabpage I cant use the mousewheel to scroll in that tabpage unless I manually click a control within the tabpage and thats what I'm trying to figure out how to fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't get a repro of this problem.  Something that might help is to set the focus to the first control of the page instead, just like what happens when you fix the problem by clicking a control.  And to do so later, after the combobox event is completed.   Use this:

```
    private void setFocusToPage(TabPage page) {
        var ctl = page.Controls.Count > 0 ? page.Controls[0] : page;
        this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { ctl.Focus(); });
    }
```

Call setFocusToPage instead of the Focus() method in your SelectedIndexChanged event handler.